# NodeJS - Keep my App running with Forever

Tags: node.js, forever, hapi.js, monit

Currently, I have a NodeJS service running on my server. It provides a RestAPI thanks to HAPI.JS

This service run permanently with **forever** executed in **upstart** script but I got some trouble.

Sometimes, the service have an error like this :

```html
Debug: internal, implementation, error 
    TypeError: Uncaught error: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined....
```

At this moment, server is completly down and never restart :(

I need a 100% stable service that why I have to restart it when an error appears.

My Question :

## How can I restart NodeJS Service with forever when errors occured ?

Comment: can you post the code that is throwing the error?

Comment: 1. Find the error trace 2. Can you place your forever command?

Comment: This error was just an example. I able to fix it, this is not the problem. I may have other kind of error that occured and I can't forecast it that why I need to restart my process.

Comment: my command is simple (in upstart or directly in command line) : 
 - forever start restAPI/index.js
 - forever restart restAPI/index.js

And then I look up the log in /root/.forever/MYUID.log

Answer (score 1):

Run you app with [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) instead of forever. Pm2 will restart the node server even after uncaught exceptions.

Comment: Ohhh it seems good. I will try it and I return my feeling about PM2. Thank You.

Comment: You're welcome and happy day to the no commenter down-voter! :)

Comment: Woooww, I set up PM2 and it's a very powerful solution. I use KeyMetrics webpage to monit my bucket. It's amazing. May I take Premium account in few months. Thank you again Marekful ;)

Comment: I assume the downvote is because your answer doesn't really answer the question. It's a perfectly valid real world solution but it by passes the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the process fails on startup then it won't restart automatically. You can configure the minimum uptime `--minUptime` flag.

You can then use the `--watch` flag to watch for changes of the fix.

However, the specific error you're receiving wouldn't normally stop the Hapi process which would suggest this isn't a `forever` issue.

Comment: You mean that my Hapi process sould restart with forever if error appears ? 
However, this is not a problem on startup so I dont think I need --minUptime.

Comment: yes, forever should keep the process running. If you run the process then `kill [pid]` on the server the process should restart.

Comment: Thank you :) but finaly, I prefer using PM2.